# Can Sun JDK generate core/heap dump files when JVM crashes?

Tags: java, coredump, jvm-crash

Is there anyway to generate core/heap dump file when JVM crashes? Since these files are usually very helpful to find out bugs in code.

Comment: Exiting due to an edception is nok a crash.

Comment: Can "throw new OutOfMemoryError()" generate a dump file? I tried, but failed. If not, can you provide a situation under which core/heap dump file can be generated. Thanks very much.

Comment: The IBM JVM can programatically be told to generate these dumps which you can then do just before System.exit(0).  I do not know of a vendor independent way to do so.

Comment: OK. I tried just a minute ago. throw new OutOfMemoryError() can not generate a dump file. Using -Xmx to limit memory space and define a large array in the code can generate a heap dump. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It would be OK if jvm crash with a OutOfMemoryError throwing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With the following JVM options:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath="/tmp"
```

JVM will dump the content of heap to a file in specified directory. Note that this only happens when `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown since dump isn't really needed if JVM crashed due to a different reason.

*Edit: "Boolean options are turned on with -XX:+ and turned off with -XX:-." [docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)*

Comment: Should be -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError (with plus symbol) because minus actually turns it off

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`-XX:HeapDump` JVM options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).