# Java application crashes when starting full screen application

Tags: java, jetty, fullscreen, runtime-error

I have a small Java application that starts a small Jetty server. This usually works great.

Unfortunately, when I start a completely unrelated, non-Java full screen game (I tried with World of Warcraft and SW: TOR), the app immediately crashes. It does not leave a hs_err log file to tell me why. It simply dies with the Windows "This app has stopped working"-dialog. The game itself continues running fine. It crashes on any game I've tried, but not on full screen video players. It crashes both if started from Eclipse and from command line. I haven't been able to reproduce this with another Java application, from simple to very large ones. When I start WoW in fullscreen (windowed) mode, the app continues running fine, so it seems this is triggered by having a full screen app that takes control of the entire desktop.

It seems like that for some reason the JVM crashes when my video card starts doing something.

Does anyone have an idea why this crash happens, or how I can figure out why it does? I'm not sure how starting a completely unrelated application (video driver maybe?) would interfere with my JVM.

Comment: Stack Trace? And the relevant code?

Comment: There is no stack trace, the app just crashes. That's the problem - I don't have anywhere to start looking.

Comment: Crashes with no stack trace at all? That seems very odd indeed...

Comment: Please expand on *"full screen game"*.  What form does the game take? E.G. Is it an applet, an application, an HTML based web-app, a zeppelin..?  Is the code digitally signed?  If so, is the user prompted to accept the digitally signed code?  Also for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It almost seems there is a problem with the video card on that machine that is triggered by Java full screen mode, though I find your description a little contradictory and confusing.  Does *"It crashes on any game I've tried"* mean 'all Java based games when sent to full screen'?

Comment: Updated question for clarity, thanks for the comments so far :)

Comment: the hs_err file would seem to be the place to contain additional information (e.g. a JVM crash in native code), but without that, I suggest running your JVM from a debugger or IDE of some kind.  Perhaps that would print more information about the crash.  I suspect a JVM bug, or a video driver bug, or a windows bug.  Have you tried another OS, or a different windows PC?

Comment: sorry, you did mention eclipse, but is there anything in the error console?

Comment: No, there's nothing. I can see the status in Eclipse going from running to stopped, but nothing (other than the app's logging that was alreayd there) appears in either the console or the Eclipse error log. Is there some Eclipse or JVM parameter that I can enable for extra debugging?

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with screen resolution changes that often happen when sending a game to fullscreen?

Comment: That might be, but WoW is running in the same resolution as my desktop normally is. SW:TOR is running in a different one.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this on other machine configurations (different OS or different video card)? Does your app have any UI? Is it your app that crashes or the Jetty server? Have you tried commenting out large chunks of your app (or starting from 'Hello World' and adding bits of your app bit by bit) to see if that helps narrow down the cause?  The more things you've tried (and tell us about), the more you're likely to get the answer you're looking for (whether from us or your own discovery)...

Comment: Windows eventvwr doesn't tell anything ? Which version of windows are you running ? Have you tried to change binding ports of jetty (some anti-hack programs are "aggressive". When you change resolution on your desktop your app crashes ? (Please also add GPU model and driver version)

Comment: Try to start eclipse with the parameters -debug -consolelog. Is anything useful displayed here? Have you tried to run the program from a dos box to see if anything gets printed to stdout or stderr?

Comment: I'm experiencing this with my program (https://github.com/tarehart/alter) and it's driving me crazy. It crashes when the Battlefield 4 beta goes full screen (which rather defeats the purpose). I also get no hs_err, only "Process finished with exit code -1073740771".

Answer (score 0):

You can try to monitor it with visual vm. Also try to write a heap dump when the vm crashes and analyse it afterwards. Maybe then you will get an idea of what happens.

[Can Sun JDK generate core/heap dump files when JVM crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944082/can-sun-jdk-generate-core-heap-dump-files-when-jvm-crashes)

Tried any newer Java version?

Answer (score -1):

Is yours  game Warcraft and SW: TOR game is running concurrently? Do you mean that  you are running yours game build under java and at that instance you started  another game  Warcraft and SW: TOR? Which operating system and which version of J V M are you using?May be the two different program is having different priority for graphics resources.It not clear that the game Warcraft and SW: TOR is build under which platform .May be the operating system default priority of thread scheduling is working behind for using graphics resources.It seems like JV M is throwing system exception for not finding the resource and terminating .May be you should check the availability of resources and if it is available proceed forward.